# Excel recursion - find last in a sequence

Tags: excel, vba, recursion

Using Excel 2010 & have a list of parts, some of which can have their part number changed.  If a part has been changed, it will be in one worksheet (Column A), and its new value (column B). There is also a date time stamp on the change.

[image: OldValue to NewValue]

In my list of all part numbers, I need to

1. Check to see if the part has been changed, and
2. Follow it through each of it's changes until I find the last one.

The "*last one*" can mean EITHER

- The value in Column B (**newVal**) is not in Column A(**oldval**) OR
- If it refers back to itself (a correction), in which case the newest Date Time stamp is the determining factor.

Corrections to the list are entered by adding a row which would redirect it to the previous (correct) version.  An example:

- oldVal A changes to newVal B   2016-04-08 11:39:04.765
- oldVal B changes to newVal C   2016-04-08 12:21:39.801
- (*we find out the B--> C change is incorrect*)
- oldVal C changes to newVal B   2016-04-08 13:44.07.913

I know that a vLookup won't do this.  I think that SUMPRODUCT may solve the first part, but I'm not sure how to do the recursion (or if it's possible) for the time part of it.

Any thoughts, ideas, solutions would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Additional Info -

The desired output 
[image: Desired Output]

What I want to show in the **NewPartNo** column is the last value in the chain for that part number.  If the Part number went from A --> B --> C --> D, I would want to see D in the **NewPartNo** column for the **PartNo** in column A.

*You have a 1960-1 that has a newVal of 25-1960. The problem is that the 25-1960 then has a newVal of OBB1960. How many levels of recursive misplaced vals are there?*

That's the issue - in some places a part may be (originally) named any one of the ones in column A.  As far as how many levels - I don't know.  Possibly 5-10, maybe?  I don't know exactly.

**EDIT 2**

@TMDean's solution mostly worked, except for when I had data like below.

[image: Recursion]

If starting with A001, it maps to B001.  B001's newest (most recent date) mapping is to C001.  C001's mapping (to itself) has the same date-time stamp as the other one, so A001 should map to C001.

In stepping through the function, it will find the first one (A001 -> B001), but throws an error when it tries to find the second one (B001 -> C001).

In the above, the correct result of the lookup should be A001 -> C001.

Comment: You have a 1960-1 that has a *newVal* of 25-1960. The problem is that the 25-1960 then has a *newVal* of OBB1960. How many levels of recursive misplaced vals are there? For that matter, I cannot se any part of the narrative that describes what you want as output and what you want to do with it once you've achieved it.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two UDFs¹ to retrieve the recursive *newVal* and it's associated date.

```
Option Explicit

Function newestVal(lu As Range, rng As Range)
    Dim val As Variant
    Static app As New Application

    'truncate the rng down to the used range
    Set rng = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange)
    val = lu.Value2

    With rng
        If IsError(app.Match(lu.Value2, .Columns(1), 0)) Then
            val = app.Index(.Columns(2), app.Match(val, .Columns(2), 0), 1)
        Else
            Do While Not IsError(app.Match(val, .Columns(1), 0))
                val = app.Index(.Columns(2), app.Match(val, .Columns(1), 0), 1)
            Loop
        End If
    End With

    newestVal = val
End Function

Function latestValDate(lu As Range, rng As Range)
    Dim d As Long, val As Variant, dbl As Double
    Static app As New Application

    'truncate the rng down to the used range
    Set rng = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange)
    val = lu.Value2

    With rng
        If IsError(app.Match(lu.Value2, .Columns(1), 0)) Then
            val = app.Index(.Columns(2), app.Match(val, .Columns(2), 0), 1)
        Else
            Do While Not IsError(app.Match(val, .Columns(1), 0))
                val = app.Index(.Columns(2), app.Match(val, .Columns(1), 0), 1)
            Loop
        End If

        For d = app.Match(val, .Columns(2), 0) To rng.Rows.Count
            If .Cells(d, 2).Value2 = val Then
                If .Cells(d, 3).Value2 > dbl Then
                    dbl = .Cells(d, 3).Value2
                End If
            End If
        Next d
    End With

    latestValDate = dbl
End Function
```

In F2:G2 as,

```
=newestVal(E2,A:C )
=latestValDate(E2,A:C )
```

[image: recursive_newval]

---

¹ <sub>A User Defined Function (aka UDF) is placed into a standard module code sheet. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, immediately use the pull-down menus to **Insert ► Module** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>). Paste the function code into the new module code sheet titled something like *Book1 - Module1 (Code)*. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet(s).</sub>

Comment: Think you missed the requirement that the old code and new code can flip flop between the same values. E.g. A -> B -> A I think your first UDF will loop infinitely in that case. I think you have to loop through the rows, but you should be able to combine the two UDFs into one with an optional parameter of the column # to return.

Comment: @Tmdean - I was going to post the same thing.  And that's exactly what it does if I have one go from A--> B--> C --> B.  The change date is only relevant when it becomes a circular reference.  You would follow the change from A->B->C->B  but would not process the B->C a second time, because the chgDate on C->B is newer than the chgDate on the original B->C mapping.

Comment: I can see one possible solution but it would require that the *chgDate* column be sorted in an ascending manner. While a large block of data with unsorted dates would still be possible, it simply isn't worth it. At some point you just have to declare [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) and walk away from it.

Comment: @Jeeped - it shouldn't be a problem to sort them by chgDate.  The only issue I could foresee would be the case I added earlier today, where the mapping of A001 - > B001 was newer than the mapping of B001 -> C001.

Answer (score 1):

This is all psuedo code but it should get you ion the right direction. Give me a couple of hours and I can do it for you, but it might be fun for you to try and figure it out.

```
    If Selection Offset Column + 1 <> vbNullString then
    newvalue = Selection Offset Column + 1.value
    for i = 1 to 100
    If newvalue Offset Column + 1 = vbNullString then
        Display (i)a,b,c
        Exit For
    ElseIf newvalue Offset Column + 1 <> vbNullString then
    newvalue = newvalue Offset Column + 1.value
    Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Jeeped's solution, I wondered if it could be more general purpose and wrote a UDF implementation of a recursive version of `VLOOKUP`.

This function works just like `VLOOKUP` except it will follow the chain of lookup values until it gets to the end of the table, as described in the problem.

```
Option Explicit

Function VLOOKUPR(LookupValue As Variant, _
                  TableArray As Range, _
                  ColIndexNum As Long, _
                  RangeLookup As Boolean)
    Dim LookupIndex

    Set TableArray = Intersect(TableArray, TableArray.Parent.UsedRange)
    VLOOKUPR = CVErr(xlErrNA)

    Do
        LookupIndex = Application.Match(LookupValue, TableArray.Columns(1), _
                                        IIf(RangeLookup, 1, 0))
        If IsError(LookupIndex) Then Exit Do

        VLOOKUPR = TableArray(LookupIndex, ColIndexNum)
        If LookupValue <> TableArray(LookupIndex, 1) Then Exit Do

        LookupValue = TableArray(LookupIndex, ColIndexNum)
        Set TableArray = Intersect(TableArray, TableArray.Offset(LookupIndex))
    Loop Until TableArray Is Nothing
End Function
```

Since I wanted it to be general purpose, I didn't include the requirement that it return the lookup value instead of `#N/A` if it exists in column B. You can include this logic in the cell formula you use to call `VLOOKUPR`. `=IFERROR(VLOOKUPR($E2,$A$2:$A$100,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP($E2,$B$2:$B$100,1,FALSE))`

Comment: this mostly works, but I've found a case that it hasn't.  Editing the original question to include this.